# Not sure what I am doing wrong... - ||| PYTHON |||

Tags: python, programming-languages

I am doing a thing while following a tutorial. I think I did everything correct but when starting the program I am getting an error.

Here are my files codes:

1) the main file - frs.py

```
from parser import Parser
from lexer import Lexer

def main():
    filename = 'hello.frs'
    file     = open(filename, 'r')
    lexer    = Lexer(file)
    parser   = Parser(lexer.tokens)

    lexer.tokenizer()
    print ("TOKENS:")
    print (lexer.tokens, "\n")

    parser.build_AST()
    print ("AST:")
    print (parset.AST, "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

2) the Lexer class - lexer.py

```
class Lexer:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.tokens = []
        self.keywords = [
            'tosay'
        ]

    def tokenizer(self):
        for loc in self.data:
            tmp = []
            tid = ''

            for l in loc:
                if l == '"' and tid == '':
                    tid = 'char'
                    tmp = []
                elif l == '"' and tid == 'char':
                    self.tokens.append({'id': tid, 'value': ''.join(tmp)})
                    tid = ''
                    tmp = []
                elif l == ':':
                    self.tokens.append({'id': 'label', 'value': ''.join(tmp)})
                    tmp = []
                elif ''.join(tmp) in self.keywords:
                    self.tokens.append({'id': 'keyword', 'value': ''.join(tmp)})
                    tmp = []
                elif l == ' ' and tid != 'char':
                    continue
                else:
                    tmp.append(l)
```

3) the Parser class - parser.py

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens
        self.AST    = []

    def add_node(self, parent, node):
        for a in self.AST:
            if parent in a:
                a[parent].append(node)

    def build_AST(self):
        saved   = {}
        parent  = {}
        collect = False

        for token in self.tokens:
            if token['id'] == 'label':
                t = {token['value']: []}

                if parent != t:
                    parent = token['value']
                    self.AST.append(t)

            elif token['id'] == 'keyword':
                if token['value'] == 'stop':
                    t = {token['value']: 0}
                    self.add_node(parent, t)
                else:
                    if collect ==  False:
                        saved = token
                        collect = True
                    else:
                        t = {saved['value']: token[:value]}
                        self.add_node(parent, t)
                        collect = False

            elif token['id'] == 'char':
                if collect = False:
                    saved = token
                    collect = True
                else:
                    t = {saved['value']: token['value']}
                    self.add_node(parent, t)
                    collect = False
```

4) the file with my own language and is a goal of the tutorial - hello.frs:

```
commence:
    tosay "Hello World"
stop
```

Basically, until I added the `from parser import Parser`, everything worked. But after adding, I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "frs.py", line 1, in <module>
  from parser import Parser
ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'
```

I tried renaming the class, but it still doesn't work.
Please help me!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: parser.py has an error.  Change `if collect = False:` to `if collect == False:`.

Comment: frs.py has an eerror.  Change `print (parset.AST, "\n")` to ` print (parset.AST, "\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors in your files.

1) File parser.py:

Change:

```
if collect = False:
```

To

```
if collect == False:
```

2) File frs.py

Change:

```
print (parset.AST, "\n")
```

To:

```
print (parser.AST, "\n")`
```

**After Above Corrections My Output**

```
TOKENS:
[{'id': 'label', 'value': 'commence'}, {'id': 'keyword', 'value': 'tosay'}, {'id': 'char', 'value': 'Hello World'}] 

AST:
[{'commence': [{'tosay': 'Hello World'}]}]
```

Comment: i fixed the "parset" and "collect =" stuff, but it still says that i can't import it.